# Вывод в csv по столбцам (python)

Tags: python, csv

Как записать имеющие списки в csv файл по разным столбцам, чтобы еще вначале название столбцов (хедеры) написать.
А то у меня код записывает все в один столбец построчно.
Вот код:

```
import csv
from mypars import all_id_z
from mypars import all_href_z

id_z = all_id_z
href_z = all_href_z

with open('zakup.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for item in id_z:
        csv_writer.writerow([item])
    for item in href_z:
        csv_writer.writerow([item])
```

Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: длина у списков одинаковая?

Comment: @MaxU да одинаковая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если длина списков одинаковая то можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = [3,5,8,9,1]
lst3 = [3,-11,0,2,7]

data = dict(col1=lst1, col2=lst2, col3=lst3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/res.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

результат:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(Path(r'c:/temp/res.csv').read_text())
```

---

```
col1;col2;col3
1;3;3
2;5;-11
3;8;0
4;9;2
5;1;7
```

Comment: а как другой разделить поставить место запятой?

Comment: @NikitaAfanasev, `df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/res.csv', sep=';', index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Либо же можно сделать это с помощью стандартного модуля csv. Объединяешь свои списки в список списков.

```
import csv

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8] 

data = [list1,list2]

path = "output.csv"
with open(path, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Выходные данные в файле:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: то, что список должен быть строкой с таблице, я правильно понял? или как в ответе MaxU, список должен быть столбцом?